# What threats come from CRLF in email generation?

Tags: injection, smtp

I have an application where a code scanner has identified CRLF injection possibilities in some classes related to email generation.

I understand how CRLF injection could be used against me on URL-based attacks, but google has been kinda silent on threats coming from email.  Are we concerned with injecting different addresses in SMTP conversations like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example

?

Or something else?

Comment: Do you have a specific reference id from your code scanner?

Comment: Multiple hits.  And I'm security-minded, I'm just trying to decide what the threat basis is in the first place.  I can't see how I'd want to exploit this for nefarious ends.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on how your application creates the actual RAW email request, it may be possible to insert line feeds to modify the recipients, CC, BCC etc.

Check out [this example](http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection#What.27s_the_point_of_injecting_email_headers_.3F):

> In this context, the target is to be able to send anonymous emails to
>   other recipients. There are numerous additional fields that can be
>   specified in the mail headers (see [ RFC 822 ]). For example 'Cc'
>   (Carbon Copy), which sends a copy of the message to the email
>   addresses given as arguments. A better choice is to use the 'Bcc'
>   (Blind Carbon Copy) which sends a carbon copy of the message just like
>   with the 'Cc' header, except that the recipiends email addresses given
>   as arguments are not shown to the multiple recipients' headers. As
>   specified in the [ RFC 822 ], one must add a line feed for every
>   header. The  (line feed) char has a hexadecimal value of 0x0A.
>
> ```
>   Sender: "sender@anonymous.www%0ACc:recipient@someothersite.xxx%0ABcc:somebloke@grrrr.xxx,someotherbloke@oooops.xxx"
>
>   Subject: ahem
>   Message: "My Message"
> ```

will result in

> ```
>  To: recipient@victim.xxx 
>  Subject: ahem
>  From: sender@anonymous.xxx
>  Cc:recipient@someothersite.xxx
>  Bcc:somebloke@grrrr.xxx,someotherbloke@oooops.xxx
>
>  My Message...
> ```

Also, check out some [OWASP Guidance](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_IMAP/SMTP_Injection_%28OWASP-DV-011%29), and some examples under [CWE-93](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/93.html).

Answer (score 8):

Here is an [example of a PHP mail-generating script that is vulnerable to a CRLF-injection attack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43091/9357).  In essence, the problematic code was:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}"; //create headers
mail('opps@example.com',$subject,$content,$headers); //mails it
```

In that case, a poorly designed PHP API was difficult to use correctly.  As a result, a web-based contact form could be used to send arbitrary spam, if an attacker made a POST request whose `email` parameter ended with a <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>`CC: victim@example.net`.

I invite you to submit your code to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), where we can go over all aspects of your code, including potential security issues such as CRLF injection.